# Can naturalized Argentina citizens renounce their citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, argentina

Argentinians born in Argentina cannot renounce their citizenship

Is it the same for naturalized ones?

Comment: Just contact the Argentine representation in your country of residence, or the Cancilleria in Argentina. That being said, a simple google search turns up that there is no mechanism for renouncing argentine nationality.

Comment: Please supply the exact wording of the Argentinian law that does not allow the renouncement. If there is no meantion of naturalized citizens, then it most likely applies to everyone.

Comment: How is this question on-topic here? It's not related to expatriates or expatriation.

Comment: I think that once you have naturalised in a country you cease being an expat, no? I think Law is more likely as well

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it helps expats choose whether to naturalize.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thanks, I never thought of that. I'll withdraw my vtc.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt,DavidSupportsMonica 'it helps expats choose whether to naturalize' It won't help expats at all if those who **can answer the question** (at **law.stackexchange**) never see the question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I've seen lawyers on expats too. But anyway, no strong preference, we need https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt,DavidSupportsMonica It looks as if the OP took my adviced and has recieved an answer. [Can naturalized Argentina citizens renounce their citizenship? - Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/82427/25602)